# Do spellcheckers exist that are aware of Markdown?

Tags: shell, spell-checking

I would like to run a spellchecker over my articles before I publish them. I think `aspell` is ok, but it should not try to check code blocks:

````
asdfasdfa adsfa sdfa text to check adsfasd f

```
a wild code block appeared!
thisHas quiteOften() some strings.that should NOT get changed
```

and also `inlined code` should not get checked
````

**Do command line based spellcheckers exist for Linux that are aware of Markdown and hence ignore code blocks?** I need to be able to run this in batch mode for multiple files.

(Bonus points if you know one that really understands LaTeX - no, `aspell -t` does not completely work)

Comment: Which editor? I use `flyspell-mode` with `ispell` in emacs and I've set it up to ignore LaTeX commands. Works fine.

Comment: I use `vim` to do textile for posting to my blog and I believe that is aware of the markup, so they exist.

Comment: As far as I can tell, aspell is aware of markdown nowadays. A quick google finds [several](https://www.manuel-strehl.de/check_markdown_spelling_with_aspell) [results](https://roneo.org/en/markdown-spellcheck-multiple-files-with-aspell/) as long as you are prepared to read the file all at once, and not in a line-based filter. aspell manual: http://aspell.net/man-html/The-Options.html

Answer (score 6):

I'm going for the bonus points. I use `emacs` and have `flyspell-mode` enabled by default for LaTeX documents. It works fine and ignores LaTeX commands.

The relevant lines in my `.emacs` file are:

```
;; load flyspell-mode for LaTeX files
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode) 

;; make flyspell mode ignore latex commands
(setq ispell-extra-args '("--dont-tex-check-comments"))
```

Haven't really used markdown much but I'd guess you can do the equivalent for it as well.

Comment: emacs seems not to ignore HTML by default. The first spellcheck-errors I got were from `<li>`-tags.

Comment: I've asked for a shell based spellchecker, because I would like to check about 400 markdown files. If the spellchecker does not find an error, it should simply quit (without opening a window). I think emacs is not Shell based, is it?

Comment: @moose I had not understood that you wanted a commandline utility that an run on multiple files. Emacs might well be able to do this (it does everything else after all) but I don't know how. The `flyspell` mode simply highlights errors as you type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I think it might be a very good choice for new documents (+1), but for by old documents it doesn't help. I'm sorry for not being clear about the commandline / batch part of the question.

Comment: > “Haven't really used markdown much but I'd guess you can do the equivalent for it as well.”
␤
Why'd you guess so? I don't really see the link between ispell having latex support and it purportedly also having markdown support.

Comment: @rien333 as I say in the answer, I was going for the bonus points. If you read the question, you will see that the bonus points were offered for a spell checker that can deal with LaTeX.

Comment: My bad, didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: @rien333 no worries, I know exactly how that feels :) I'll be deleting our comments soon.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [markdown-spellcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-spellcheck) is the right tool for you. You need to install `nodejs/npm`.

Test run in interactive mode:

````
$ cat test.md 
asdfasdfa adsfa sdfa text to check adsfasd f

```
a wildwild code block appppeared!
thisHas quiteOften() some strings.that should NOT get changed
```

and also `inLIned code` should not get checked
$ mdspell test.md 
Spelling - test.md
asdfasdfa adsfa sdfa text to check adsf
?   Ignore
asdfasdfa adsfa sdfa text to check adsfasd f
?   Ignore
asdfasdfa adsfa sdfa text to check adsfasd f
?   Ignore
sdfa adsfa sdfa text to check adsfasd f
?   Ignore
>> 1 file is free from spelling errors
````

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use ignores code blocks.
It's based on aspell and supports 90+ languages

Here is a short howto, you may want to check [the original post](https://roneo.org/en/markdown-spellcheck-multiple-files-with-aspell/) for screenshots and better formatting

#### 1. Install aspell

Here with the english dictionnary:

```bash
sudo apt install aspell aspell-en
```

A list of available dictionnaries can be found on [gnu.org](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html)

#### 2. Open a terminal

#### 3. Navigate to the root of your project

#### 4. Run the following command:

```bash
grep -rlP 'title:' content/ | xargs -o -n1 sh -c 'aspell check "$@" --master=en_US --lang=en_US  --sug-mode=slow -x --mode=markdown < /dev/tty' whatever
```

(You may want to adjust `content/` and `--master=en_US --lang=en_US`)

#### 5. Browse the suggestions and apply with a single keystroke

(Shortcuts and suggestions are shown at the bottom of the screen)

See [this post for screenshots](https://roneo.org/en/markdown-spellcheck-multiple-files-with-aspell/)